# TextVectorization and Autoencoder for feature extraction of text

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, autoencoder, feature-engineering

I'm trying to solve a problem which is as follows:

I need to train the autoencoder to extract useful data from text. I will use the trained autoencoder in another model to extract features.

The goal is to teach the autocoder to compress the information and then reconstruct the exact same string. I solve the problem of classification for each letter.

My dataset:

```
X_train_autoencoder_raw:

15298    some text...
1127     some text...
22270    more text...
                               ...                        
Name: data, Length: 28235, dtype: object
```

Now I want to use the TextVectorization:

```
#Turn data into Tensorflow datasets
text_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X_train_autoencoder_raw)

def char_split(input_data):
   return tf.strings.unicode_split(input_data, 'UTF-8')
    
vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(max_tokens=max_features,
                                                    output_mode='tf_idf',
                                                    split=char_split,
                                                   )

vectorize_layer.adapt(text_dataset.batch(64))
```

And I get the dictionary:

```
vocab = np.array(vectorize_layer.get_vocabulary())
vocab

array(['[UNK]', 't', 'o', 's', 'о', 'e', 'a', 'е', 'а', 'т', 'и', 'r',
       'н', 'p', 'n', 'с', 'i', 'd', 'р', 'л', 'h', 'в', 'u', 'м', 'к',
       'l', 'п', 'y', 'у', 'д', 'g', 'b', 'я', 'c', 'w', 'ы', 'ь', 'ч',
       ' ', 'm', 'f', 'г', 'з', 'б', '1', 'й', 'ж', '2', '3', 'ю', 'k',
       '4', 'х', 'ш', 'v', '0', '7', '8', '5', '6', 'А', 'С', '9', 'Н',
       'э', 'В', 'О', 'x', 'К', 'И', 'Р', 'П', 'Е', '–', 'ц', 'щ', 'q',
       'Д', 'М', 'ф', 'Л', 'Т', 'ё', 'Б', '«', 'Я', 'У', '»', 'Ч', 'j',
       'Ф', 'z', 'Ь', 'Ы', '…', 'Х', '—', 'З', 'Г', 'Ж', 'Э', 'ř', 'Ц',
       'Ё', 'Ю', 'Й', '№', 'Щ', '€', '⋮', 'ъ', '’', '“', '”', 'í', 'á',
       'Ш', 'ú', 'é', 'è', '„', '‘', 'ν', 'Ъ', 'ω', 'ρ', 'ο', 'ι', 'ζ',
       'α', 'ô', 'ç', 'à', 'Í', 'Á'], dtype='<U5')
```

Turn data into Tensorflow datasets:

```
X_train_autoencoder = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X_train_autoencoder_raw)
X_train_autoencoder = text_dataset.batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Building model:

```
token_embed=tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=len(vectorize_layer.get_vocabulary()),
                             output_dim=128,
                             mask_zero=True,
                             name="token_embedding")
inputs=tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype="string")
text_vectors=vectorize_layer(inputs)
token_embedding=token_embed(text_vectors)
x=tf.keras.layers.GRU(64, return_sequences=True)(token_embedding)
x=tf.keras.layers.GRU(32, return_sequences=False)(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(135)(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.GRU(64, return_sequences=False)(x)
x=tf.keras.layers.Dense(128)(x)
outputs=tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(vectorize_layer.get_vocabulary()),activation="softmax")(x)
# Indirect way of creating the Modelling the op ip
model_1=tf.keras.Model(inputs,outputs)
# Compiling the Model
model_1.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=["accuracy"])
```

summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_28 (InputLayer)        [(None, 1)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
text_vectorization_1 (TextVe (None, 135)               1         
_________________________________________________________________
token_embedding (Embedding)  (None, 135, 128)          17280     
_________________________________________________________________
gru_51 (GRU)                 (None, 135, 64)           37248     
_________________________________________________________________
gru_52 (GRU)                 (None, 32)                9408      
_________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_11 (RepeatVect (None, 135, 32)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
gru_53 (GRU)                 (None, 64)                18816     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_30 (Dense)             (None, 128)               8320      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_31 (Dense)             (None, 135)               17415     
=================================================================
Total params: 108,488
Trainable params: 108,487
Non-trainable params: 1
```

But now if I try to train a model:

```
history_model_1=model_1.fit(X_train_autoencoder,
                            epochs=5,
                           )
```

I get an error:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['token_embedding/embeddings:0', 'gru_51/gru_cell_51/kernel...
```

The other option leads to another error:

```
history_model_1=model_1.fit(X_train_autoencoder,
                            X_train_autoencoder,
                            epochs=5,
                           )

ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using dataset as input.
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `tf.data.Dataset` you should combine your inputs and outputs in a single `Dataset` object.

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (
        (feature1, feature2), # model inputs
        (label1, label2) # model outputs
    )
)
```